# SQL Server : optimize the efficiency with many joins relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server code which takes long time to run the result. In the past, it took 15 minutes. But recently, might as a result of accumulated sales data, it took 2 hours to get the result!!

Therefore, I would like to get some advice regarding how to optimize the code:

The code structure is simple: just to get the sales sum for different regions for different time periods and for each SKU. (I have deleted some code here is to find the different SKU for each materials without size).

Many thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

The main code structure is as below, since it is almost the same, so I just give the first 2 paragraphs as example:

```js
SELECT SKU from [MATINFO]

-- Global Sales History Qty - All the years

   LEFT JOIN
   (
    SELECT SKU,SUM([SALES Qty]) as [Global Sales History Qty - All the years]
    from dbo.[SALES]
    
    where [PO] IS NOT NULL

    group by SKU

   )histORy

   on MATINFO.[SKU]=histORy.[SKU]


-- Global Sales History Qty - Past 2 years

 LEFT JOIN
   (
    SELECT (
     SELECT SKU,SUM([SALES Qty]) as [Global Sales History Qty - All the years]
      from dbo.[SALES]
    
      where [PO] IS NOT NULL

      group by SKU

    /* date range */
    and ([ORDER DATE] = '2015.11' OR [ORDER DATE] = '2015.12'  or [ORDER DATE] like '%2015%' OR [ORDER DATE] like '%2016%' ) 
    group by SKU
   )histORy2

   on MATINFO.[SKU]=histORy2.[SKU]

--Global Sales History Qty - Past 1 years

......SIMILAR TO THE CODE STRUCTURE AS ABOVE
```

Comment: Materialize your derived tables in temporary tables (with suitable indexes), and use the temporary tables in your grand query instead.

Comment: @ TT., Thanks for your prompt reply. It is pretty helpful. Could you please type your reply in "Answer Area" and give a short example, so I could adopt it?

Comment: Did my answer speed up your query?

Comment: @ TT. I faced another problem for not using the string as the criteria to filter as explained in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466817/sql-server-the-date-format-changes-to-nvchar-when-excel-imported-into-sql-serv. It would be great help if you could help answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expansion on my comment. Note it is just a suggestion, no guarantee if will run faster.

Take the following derived table `histORy`:

```
SELECT SKU,SUM([SALES Qty]) AS [Global Sales History Qty - All the years]
FROM dbo.[SALES]
WHERE [PO] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SKU
```

Before you run your query, materialize the derived table in a temporary table:

```
SELECT SKU,SUM([SALES Qty]) AS [Global Sales History Qty - All the years]
INTO #histORy
FROM dbo.[SALES]
WHERE [PO] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SKU
```

Then use the temporary table in the query:

```
LEFT JOIN #histORy AS h ON MATINFO.[SKU]=h.[SKU]
```

In this case you may want to have a index on the `SKU` field, so you could create the temporary table yourself, slap an index on it, populate with `INSERT INTO #history... SELECT ...` etc.

Comment: Many thanks, it works. I combined your and Used_By_Already's methods and finally it just took 3 minutes to get results.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause of the poor performance is using string for dates and possibly the lack if as adequate  indexes.

**like '%2015%'**

Using double-ended wildcards with like results  in full table scans so subqueries are scanning the whole table each time you serach for a different date range. Using temp tables will not solve the underlying issues.

---

[added later]

Another facet of your original query structure might reduce the number of scans you need of the data - by using "conditional aggregates"

e.g. here is a condensed version of your original query

```
    SELECT
            SKU
    FROM [MATINFO]
    -- Global Sales History Qty - All the years
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                    SKU
                  , SUM([SALES Qty]) AS [Global Sales History Qty - All the years]
            FROM dbo.[SALES]
            WHERE [PO] IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY
                    SKU) histORy ON MATINFO.[SKU] = histORy.[SKU]
    -- Global Sales History Qty - Past 2 years
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                    SKU
                  , SUM([SALES Qty]) AS [Global Sales History Qty - Past 2 years]
            FROM dbo.[SALES]
            WHERE [PO] IS NOT NULL
            /* date range */
            AND [ORDER DATE] >= '20151101' AND [ORDER DATE] < '20161101'
            GROUP BY
                    SKU) histORy2 ON MATINFO.[SKU] = histORy2.[SKU]
```

That requires a 2 complete passes of the data in dbo.[SALES], but if you were to use a case expression inside the SUM() function you need only one pass of the data (in this example)

```
SELECT
        SKU
      , SUM([SALES Qty])          AS [Qty_all_years]
      , SUM(CASE
                WHEN [ORDER DATE] >= '20151101' AND [ORDER DATE] < '20161101' 
                THEN [SALES Qty]
        END)                      AS [Qty_past_2_years]
FROM dbo.[SALES]
WHERE [PO] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
        SKU
```

I suspect you could apply this logic to most of the columns and substantially improve efficiency of the query when coupled with date columns and appropriate indexing.

Comment: many thanks for your reply. Sorry I don't quite understand "Using double-ended wildcards with like results in full table scans". I guess the date range might be the cause, but the orinal date are in different formats and some turns NULL after importing into SQL SERVER. So I have to convert them into sth. like 2015.6 (in line with some other date format in ERP)  in EXCEL before importing into SQL SERVER.

Comment: **like '%2015%'** has a wildcard at both ends = double ended wilcard = extremely inefficient

Comment: yesterday, by discarding the previous method of using string for date, the speed has been improved, but still took 1 hour to get the results. In the past, it took 2 hours. I will try to use temporary table method as well, thanks

Comment: Using "as well" is perfect. **You also need indexes!** & address those underlying issues to help build the temp tables efficiently. What is often ignored in temp table solutions is the effort taken to make them in the first place. Also adding indexes to temp tables can help with speed too. You really need to look at - and use - **execution plans** to determine where the problems are and what to do about each one. Performance tuning is often iterative and/or needs multiple actions

Comment: thanks I made some test: 1.by only using the sum(case when ) method that you listed above, it took 27 minutes to get the results; 2. By only using the temporary table method, it took 3 minutes.3. By using the sum(case when)+ temporary table, it took 1,45 minutes.

Comment: And indexing? What indexes have you used? that date column and the type column shoiluld be indexed. But I  am pleased you are seeing the impact of using multiple  approaches.

Comment: @ Used_By_Already, I used SKU as index like "CREATE INDEX [sku] on ##temptable", but it doesn't help save the time.

Comment: :) my focus has always been on the source tables and not any temp tables. That date field and the type field that are used in the where clause would be good as indexes. If changing that date from text to date made a 50% difference imagine what an indexed date might do